# After long pause, dynamically added items are not there

Tags: android, listview, pause

I have an Android App, where I have a *ListView* with a *custom adapter* and some items are **static** and some are **dynamic** (loading them from url).

It works perfect, there's no error, but when I pause my App and play with other apps (like surfing in chrome), then when I return to App, the **static** items are there, but the **dynamic** items are gone.

**EDIT:** I'm using volley StringRequest and Gson to load the items from url.

Answer (score 0):

you have to store your fetched data and you can achieve this in 2 different ways

You can save that data and restore it when you came back to your app using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // save your date like this
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
    savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
    // etc.
}


@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore your date like this and assign it to your list or where ever you need
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
    double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
    int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```

You can store it in your database and restore it back whenever you move to onRestoreSaveInstance

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //  fetch data from database and assign it back to your UI
}
```

Comment: Thanks, at least I know where the problem is, but the data I have to save is an object. Can I call my loadDynamicItems() function below onRestore method?

Comment: yes you can call it in onRestoreInstance method to restore the data back